# not exact probabilities

Tags: probability

A factory in China started making balls for ballpoint pen tips in order to
improve skipping of the pens. It was found that exactly 30% of the balls failed to improve
skipping. 10 of the balls are chosen at random to be examined. Find the probability that:
(a) Fewer than 3 failed the test
(b) More than 7 failed the test

Comment: How many balls were made in all?  Ten?

Comment: it is not known, how many balls were in total. Only it is known that 30 % is the fail probability

Answer (score 1):

If we sample from a large collection with each item having probability $\frac{3}{10}$ to fail the test, we can just use the binomial distribution. Most modern calculators have these built in (I had a booklet of tables back in school), but the formulae you just plug in are

for a):

$$\sum_{i=0}^2 \binom{10}{i} \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^i \left( \frac{7}{10}\right)^{10-i}$$

and for b):

$$\sum_{i=8}^{10} \binom{10}{i} \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^i \left( \frac{7}{10}\right)^{10-i}$$

Comment: thank you very much for the help